# Keras' ImageDataGenerator.flow() results in very low training/validation accuracy as opposed to flow_from_directory()

Tags: deep-learning, keras-2

I am trying to train a very simple model for image recognition, nothing spectacular. My first attempt worked just fine, when I used image rescaling:

```
# this is the augmentation configuration to enhance the training dataset
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1. / 255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)

# validation generator, only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size=(img_width, img_height),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
validation_data_dir,
target_size=(img_width, img_height),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical')
```

Then I simply trained the model as such:

```
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

This works perfectly fine and leads to a reasonable accuracy. Then I thought it may be a good idea to try out mean subtraction, as VGG16 model uses. Instead of doing it manually, I chose to use ImageDataGenerator.fit(). For that, however, you need to supply it with training images as numpy arrays, so I first read the images, convert them, and then feed them into it:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
featurewise_center=True,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True)

def process_images_from_directory(data_dir):
    x = []
    y = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_dir, topdown=False):
        class_names = sorted(dirs)

        global class_indices
        if len(class_indices) == 0:
            class_indices = dict(zip(class_names, range(len(class_names))))

        for dir in class_names:
            filenames = os.listdir(os.path.join(root,dir))
            for file in filenames:
                img_array = img_to_array(load_img(os.path.join(root,dir,file), target_size=(224, 224)))[np.newaxis]
                if len(x) == 0:
                    x = img_array
                else:
                    x = np.concatenate((x,img_array))
                y.append(class_indices[dir])
    #this step converts an array of classes [0,1,2,3...] into sparse vectors [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], etc.
    y = np.eye(len(class_names))[y]
    return x, y

x_train, y_train = process_images_from_directory(train_data_dir)
x_valid, y_valid = process_images_from_directory(validation_data_dir)

nb_train_samples = x_train.shape[0]
nb_validation_samples = x_valid.shape[0]
train_datagen.fit(x_train)
test_datagen.mean = train_datagen.mean

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow(
        x_valid,
        y_valid,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False)
```

Then, I train the model the same way, simply giving it both iterators. After the training completes, the accuracy is basically stuck at ~25% even after 50 epochs:

80/80 [==============================] - 77s 966ms/step - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500 - val_loss: 12.0886 - val_acc: 0.2500

When I run predictions on the above model, it classifies only 1 out 4 total classes correctly, all images from other 3 classes are classified as belonging to the first class - clearly the percentage of 25% has something to do with this fact, I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I realize that I could calculate the mean manually and then simply set it for both generators, or that I could use ImageDataGenerator.fit() and then still go with flow_from_directory, but that would be a waste of already processed images, I would be doing the same processing twice.

Any opinions on how to make it work with flow() all the way?